# $(x^2-1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(4x^2-3x-5)\frac{dy}{dx}+(4x^2-6x-5)y = e^{2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please give me some hint to solve this problem because I have tried many times to solve this problem but failed:
$$
(x^2-1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(4x^2-3x-5)\frac{dy}{dx}+(4x^2-6x-5)y = e^{2x},
$$
given that $y=1$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=2$ when $x=0$.

**My attempt**

Let $y=uv$, then after solving we get $u = \frac{e^{2x}}{x^2-1}$ and invariant $I= \frac{16x^5-6x^4-32x^3+7x^2+10x-11}{4(x^2-1)^2}$.
But this value of $I$ is extremely wrong, I don't know how to obtain the correct answer.

Comment: But please give some hints

Comment: Forget the conditions first and use $u=\frac {e^{2x}}{x-1}$ to obtain a very simple differential equation.

Comment: You may also take a look at search results for [$A(x)y''(x)+B(x)y'(x)+C(x)y=D(x)$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24A(x)y%27%27%2BB(x)y%27%2BC(x)y%3DD(x)%24&p=1)